# how to add a condition such that when a dataframe has some column then only add respective "when" condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java8.
I have a scenario where I need to add a when condition on column iff that column exist in the respective dataframe . How can it be done?

Ex :

```
val df = ...// may contain columns either abc, x or y or both....depend on some business logic.

val result_df =  df
                  .withColumn("new_column", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("x"),lit("_"),col("y"))))
```

> // here the problem is some times df may not contain/fetch "x" column
>   then it should give "y" value in the result_df.  But in the above
>   statement throwing error as "x" column is not present in df at that
>   point.
>
> So how to check if a column (i.e. "x") presents the use in the
>   concat() else go with remaining columns( i.e. "y")
>
> Here vice versa also possible i.e. only col(x) presents in the df but
>   not column("y"). In some cases both columns x, y available in the df
>   then it is working fine.

Question.
 how to add the condition in when-clause as and when the column presents in the dataframe. ?

**one correction in question.**
If some colums is not there I should not go into that "withColumn" condition.

Ex :

> If column x presents :

```
val result_df =  df
                  .withColumn("new_x", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("x"))))
```

> If column x presents :

```
val result_df =  df
                  .withColumn("new_y", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("y"))))
```

> If both column x and y presents :

```
val result_df =  df
               .withColumn("new_x", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("x"))))
                .withColumn("new_y", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("y"))))
                  .withColumn("new_x_y", when(col("abc") === "a" , concat(col("x"),lit("_"),col("y"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achive that by creating a list of columns dynamically using the `columns` property and a simple if Scala/Java statement. The list should include or not the `targetColumn` depending while the columns was found or not in the dataframe schema (scala code):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat_ws}

// the column we should check for. Change this accordingly to your requirements i.e "y"
val targetColumn = "x"
var concatItems = Seq(col("y"))

// add targetColumn if found in df.columns
if (df.columns.contains(targetColumn))
  concatItems = concatItems :+ col(targetColumn)

df.withColumn("new_column", when(col("abc") === "a", concat_ws("_", concatItems:_*)))
```

Note that instead of `contact` we use `concat_ws` since it will check automatically while `contactItems` contains one or more items and apply `_` seperator respectively.

**Update:**

Here is the new updated code using a `select` statement:

```scala
var selectExpr = null

if(df.columns.contains("x") && df.columns.contains("y"))
   selectExpr = Seq(
         when(col("abc") === "a", col("x")).as("new_x"), 
         when(col("abc") === "a", col("y")).as("new_y"),
         when(col("abc") === "a", concat_ws("_", col("x"), col("y"))).as("new_x_y")
   )
else if(df.columns.contains("y"))
   selectExpr =  when(col("abc") === "a", col("y")).as("new_y")
else
   selectExpr =  when(col("abc") === "a", col("x")).as("new_x")

df.select(selectExpr:_*)
```

Note that we don't need to use `withColumn`, `select` is exactly what you need for your case.

Comment: `concat(col("x"))` or `concat(col("y"))` is the same as `col("x")` and `col("y")` so calling `concat` with only one column doesn't make sence @BdEngineer. I will update the code accordingly

Comment: `df.columns.contains(targetColumn)` is executed on the driver @BdEngineer. This code will be accessed by one thread only although I am not sure what you mean with the loop

Comment: @BdEngineer I updated the code please check and let me know if it worked

Comment: I updated the answer please check if it works. What you are asking is completely different from the initial question @BdEngineer. Please try to collect specific requirements for your questions in order to be more specific. You should avoid modifying your question continusly

Comment: is good idea to spend some time and understand how the answer work. Please try it and also try to understand the changes. If you have any question I can help to answer them. The only thing that we changed here is to replace withColumn with select. Select is much more flexible, you can achieve the same as withColumn and it can be faster

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with your languages native flow control, e.g. in python/PySpark with if, else statements.

The reason being that Spark df functions work on columns, thus you cannot apply a .when() condition checking col names, it only looks at values within the cols and applies the logic/condition row-wise.

E.g. for F.when(col(x) == col(y)), spark will translate it to Java where it'll apply that logic rowise in the two cols.

This also makes sense if you think that Spark dfs are made up of row objects, so what it does is send the condition to the drive to apply this condition to every object (row), which looks like this [Row(x=2), Row(y=5)].

```
def check_columns(df, col_x, col_y, concat_name):
    '''
    df: spark dataframe
    col_x & col_y: the two cols to concat if both present
    concat_name: name for new concated col
    -----------------------------------------------------
    returns: df with new concated col if oth x & y cols present
    otherwise if returns df with x or y col if only on present 
    '''
    cols = list(col_x) + list(col_y)
    if all(item in df.columns for item in cols) 
    df = df.withColumn(concat_name, concat(col(col_x),lit("_"),col(col_y)))
    return df
```

Only need to apply action if both x & y present as if only one is it'll return the df with the existing x or y col anyways.

I would apply something like the above, save as function for re-usability.

What you could do with .when() is only concat values where a condition is met row-wise, this will give you a col with values concated where condition is met.

```
df.when('concat_col', F.when( F.col('age') < F.lit('18'), 
                      concat(F.col('name'), F.lit('_underAge'))
                      .otherwise(F.col('name'),F.lit('_notUnderAge')))
```

Hope this helps!